# Flutter, how to change current tab bar view or page or index from child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a BottomNavigationBar

```
import 'screen_one.dart' as screen_one;
import 'screen_two.dart' as screen_two;

List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  screen_one.ScreenOne(),
  screen_two.ScreenTwo(),
];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: 
       BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    title: Text(''),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(                 
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    title: Text(''),
                  ),                         
                ],
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTap: _onItemTapped,
              ),
             body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
             ),
```

I want to change current tab index from children class (ScreenOne, ScreenTwo).

when a function occurs in ScreenOne, it needs to move on to ScreenTwo.

how could I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using callbacks,

1. Pass `_onItemTapped` as parameter to ScreenOne() : `ScreenOne(_onItemTapped)`
2. Inside `ScreenOne` : `final Function(int) onItemTapped;`
3. cCall `onItemTapped(your_index_here)`